# MSBuild 'not recognized as an internal or external command' on Hudson

Tags: c#, msbuild, hudson

I want to Start a Job on Hudson with MSBuild. But I'm getting an error.

> > > Started by user anonymous
> > >       Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
> > >       Executing the command cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe MSBuild.exe [Switches] [ProjectFile] C:\Users\praktiee4.hudson\jobs\msBuild\workspace && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Users\praktiee4.hudson\jobs\msBuild\workspace
> > >       [workspace] $ cmd.exe /C msbuild.exe MSBuild.exe [Switches] [ProjectFile] C:\Users\praktiee4.hudson\jobs\msBuild\workspace && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
> > >       'msbuild.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> > >       operable program or batch file.
> > >       Finished: FAILURE

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the Problem!

It was in my Command Line Arguments. The Arguments was wrong.

And in the System configuration i have give the Path from MSBuild.exe.